# Get the last 5 digits of an undeclared variable of unknown length on one line?

Tags: java, variables, command-line, screenshot, bit-manipulation

**Update:**

There were some great solutions, but I realized that there is a problem in my premise: It seems that the rt.exec will not reach back to the java code once the process has been executed. Thank you for all your help!

---

I want to take a screencap every second programmatically and the title of each screencap should be the timestamp. I'm using vlc to achieve this.

```
    starttime = System.nanoTime();
    screencapProcess = rt.exec("C:\\VLC\\vlc screen:// --dshow-vdev=screen-capture-recorder --dshow-fps=1 -I dummy --dummy-quiet --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --scene-format=jpg --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=" + path +" --scene-prefix="+ "ScreenCapAt" +   ( String.valueOf(((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime)).substring(9, 14))+" vlc://quit ");
```

The relevant part is:

```
    String.valueOf(((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime)).substring(9, 14))
```

This cause an index out of bounds exception for nanoTimes less that 1.

I can't declare "System.nanoTime() - starttime" as a variable outside this line to get it's length since that would change my times.

Is there a way to get the last 5 digits of this undeclared variable of unknown length on one line?

*This answer needs to fit in my rt.exec line.*

Some thoughts:

- Bitwise shifting and masking.
- Piping into my .exec
- postprocessing
- Creating a new class
- Calling System.nanoTime() - starttime again would increase the time of the operation and throw off my calculations.
- Is there a better way to atomically get the time of capture?

Comment: why are you using VLC for the screen shot , is that a requirement ???

Comment: Using vlc is not a requirement, but being able to change the fps of the screenshot is. Would you recommend a different utility?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to do it on more than one line. I don't see a way of doing it without evaluating the strings length. This is the best I could come up with:

```
String diff = ""+((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime);
String lastfive = diff.substring(Math.max(0, diff.length() - 5));
```

**UPDATE:** Found a way to do it all on one line:

```
String lastFive = (""+((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime)).replaceAll("(.*)(\\d{5}$)","$2");
```

Comment: This will not work in my rt.exec line since it is more than one line.

Comment: Updated my answer to use a regex to keep just the last 5 chars.

Comment: Nice work! Although I realized there is a problem in the way I am taking the screencaps so I'll have to rewrite it anyway. Out of curiosity, how would I take the first 5?

Comment: Flip the regex round and take the first match rather than the second: `...replaceAll("(\\d{5})(.*)$","$1")`

Answer (score 1):

In 1 line(except the declaration of calc):

```
float calc;
String diff = String.valueOf((calc = (long)System.nanoTime() - starttime)).substring(Math.max(0, String.valueOf(calc).length() - 5));
```

Comment: This looks good! I'm getting answers like 81E8, but that can be fixed by converting to seconds. Once I play around with it a little more, I'll comment a version that fits my needs better.

Comment: Also do not forget, that I'm using float calc; and long for System.nanoTime() change those types according to your needs.

Comment: Also do not forget to check if it's greater than 4 characters. This can also be done in 1 line.

Comment: I'm checking by changing the first parameter of Math.max.   System.out.println("test3 " + String.valueOf((calc = (float) (((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime)/1000000000.00))).substring(Math.max(4, String.valueOf(calc).length() - 5)));
works well. BUT when I run it in my rt.exec I get different results like ScreenCapAt0.00138500001.jpg. I'm trying a hybrid solution now where I put the line in a function and call it in my rt.exec line. Not ideal (and definitely not one line) but let's get something working and move from there :)

Comment: Okay. But what's so wrong with that result? How should it be?

Comment: That result should have been 00001.jpg - instead of 0.00138500001.jpg. I wrote your code in a function and added a print statement. However, it only prints once (but what it does print is a correct value). I think the problems I'm having now has to do with vlc or command line rather than your code.

Comment: I understand now. The code is NOT recompiling at each screenshot. The code was giving me 0.001385 (I was using the first 8 for testing instead of the last 5) and vlc tacked on 00001 at the end. Thus resulting in 0.00138500001.jpg, 0.00138500030.jpg, etc. No fault of yours, but problematic for me. I think that means that I need to take screencaps differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String diff=""+ ((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime);

 if(diff.length() >4){// Check if diff length is less than 5
   String lastFive=diff.substring(diff.length()-5, diff.length());
 }
```

Comment: This will fail if the difference between System.nanoTime() and starttime is less than 10000, which I am guessing is his problem on the first iteration

Comment: This will not work in my rt.exec line since it is more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String diff=""+ ((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime));
String lastFive=  diff.length() > 4 ? 
                 diff.substring(diff.length()-5, diff.length()) : diff;

screencapProcess = rt.exec("C:\\VLC\\vlc screen:// --dshow-vdev=screen-capture-recorder --dshow-fps=1 -I dummy --dummy-quiet --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --scene-format=jpg --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=" + path +" --scene-prefix="+ "ScreenCapAt" +  lastfive +" vlc://quit ");
```

**Update**

If you want to recalculate the value then I suggest that you put it into a seperate function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{ 

    long starttime = (long)System.nanoTime(); 
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    System.out.println("test1 " + getLastFive (starttime)); 
    Thread.sleep(500); 
    System.out.println("test2 " + getLastFive (starttime)); 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} 

static private String getLastFive (long starttime) {

    String diff=""+ ((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime); 
    String lastFive= diff.length() > 4 ? diff.substring(diff.length()-5, diff.length()) : diff; 
    return lastFive;

}
```

Comment: This will not work in my rt.exec line since it is more than one line.

Comment: use the variable lastfive in your rt.exec line.  See my updated answer

Comment: Won't this give me the same name for each screencap? The rt.exec should give me 30 or so screencaps with different names.

Comment: every time the above block of code is called, `lastfive` will be re-evaulated and then passed into rt.exec.  Why does it have to be on one line?

Comment: It is not re-evaluated.  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
  long starttime = (long)System.nanoTime();
  float calc;
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  String diff=""+ ((long)System.nanoTime() - starttime);
  String lastFive=  diff.length() > 4 ? 
                   diff.substring(diff.length()-5, diff.length()) : diff; 
  System.out.println("test1 " + lastFive);
  Thread.sleep(500);
  System.out.println("test2 " + lastFive);
  Thread.sleep(1000);} output: test1 81090
test2 81090

Comment: Will not work either since you're declaring starttime within the function itself, thus I'll get an answer under 1 second everytime. If I declared it outside the function it'd work though. Job reasonably done.

Comment: Look mate your question was originally about arrayIndexException - this has been fixed many times for you.

Comment: Please re-read the title of my post :) A separate function was a good idea and will get me what I want. BUT I asked for a one liner. I'd still prefer one. Even if I have an answer that will make my code work. I'm still curious about other/cleaner/faster ways of implementing it.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I believe that my answer with give you a cleaner and easier to read solution.  Such trivial code does not need to be faster.  As for one line, this does not give you cleaner or faster, just 'other'